# How do I implement a custom behavior in XAML

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, expression-blend

How do I implement a custom behavior in XAML specifically for Windows Phone 8.1?

I am using VS2013 and Blend 2013.

Code:

```
public class SelectionBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media" x:Name="page"

<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:SelectionBehavior />
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

When I attempt to build the solution, I receive the following errors:

> The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The
>   following type was expected: "DependencyObject".
>
> Cannot add 'SelectionBehavior' into the collection property
>   'Behaviors', type must be 'DependencyObject'
>
> A value of type 'SelectionBehavior' cannot be added to a collection or
>   dictionary of type 'BehaviorCollection'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your behavior should inherit from `DependencyObject`, try this -

```
public class SelectionBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
```

Comment: Yep! Just found it as a result of this article: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/10/introducing-win8nl-for-windows.html